# Excel VBA to open website in new tabs in firefox/chrome

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the SHELL function to open websites. The wed addresses are listed in column A. My code is working, but the websites open as new windows in chrome and firefox. How do code to make the websites open in tabs?

Update--  below is the simple code. It works for Chrome but not in firefox

```
Sub firefoxtabs()

Dim Website As String
Dim exepath As String
Dim i As Integer

'exepath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url "  'open in chrome
exepath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  'open in firefox

For i = 1 To 3
    Website = Cells(i, 1).Value
    'Shell (exepath & Website)  'for chorme
    Shell (exepath & " -new-tab " & Website)  'for firefox
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

For Firefox, try this: `firefox -new-tab $url`.

For Chrome it should be okay with just: `chrome $url`.